# bootstrapperApplicationData attribute is not declared in wix standard bootstrap application

Tags: wix

I am creating standard bootstrapper application.
I don't have any prerequisite to be installed , but I create chain of two msis and run it depending on platform.

I have added reference "WixBalExtension.dll" and added both msi as
Msipackage as chain.
I am using wix 3.8 , VS 2013.

When I compile the project its giving compilation error
"bootstrapperApplicationData' attribute is not declared".

Sample wix code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
    <Bundle Name="Bootstrapper2" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Microsoft" UpgradeCode="a084a57e-dddd-448b-b38d-2b485ff65e6d">
        <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />       
        <Chain>
            <MsiPackage Id ="a32" SourceFile="a32.msi" InstallCondition="NOT VersionNT" Compressed="no"  DisplayInternalUI="no" Vital="yes" Description="32 bit"/>
            <MsiPackage Id ="b64" SourceFile="b64.msi" InstallCondition="VersionNT"  Compressed="no"  DisplayInternalUI="no" Vital="yes" Description ="64 bit"/>
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Its a simple standard boot strapper application.
I haven't created any other dll (no customization) , so haven't added any payload.

Am I missing anything here?
How to add bootstrapperapplicationdata ? where should I add that?
Do I need to create any custom bootstrapp BA?
Do I need to add any BootstrapperCore.config or any other configuration file?

Comment: This compiles just fine for me.  Can you post your actual code instead of sample code?

Comment: This is the code except one part where I am adding property sheet.I found that importgroup or import tag is not working for this type of project to add the property sheet.

Comment: What is a property sheet?  bootstrapperApplicationData has to do with the content that goes into the BootstrapperApplicationData.xml file that custom BootstrapperApplications use.  I think you're running into a bug, or at least the error message has nothing to do with the actual error.  Please post all of your code, and possibly the .wixproj code as well if you have modified that.  Are your MSI's really in the path, or are you using absolute paths or project references?  By the way `NOT VersionNT` means Windows ME or earlier.  It should be `NOT VersionNT64` and `VersionNT64`, respectively.